# Record in Unavailable error - MS CRM Solution Export

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Whenever I try exporting a solution in MS CRM 2016, I get this error in the screenshot below where I dont find any logs too. How do I resolve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShUcy.png)

Comment: Are you system administrator?

Comment: Is trace enabled? Can you enable it with level "*:Error"?

Comment: No I am not able to download the trace log.

Comment: yes I have the system administrator privilege.

Comment: I suggest you use https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/  with All Categories selected and have the Level Set to Verbose. After you set it up, reproduce the error, collect the trace logs and use see if you can find some error in the logs. This might give you a clue. Use https://crmtracereader.codeplex.com/ for reading the trace logs